# ZendFramework 2 - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, zend-framework2, httpd.conf, apache2.4

Today I create my first project with Zend Framework2 and when using internal PHP cli-server in the root directory it works.

But when I try to configure virtual host in Apache2 I see only "500 Internal Server Error"

- ZendFramework-2.4.2
- PHP Version 5.5.9
- Apache/2.4.7

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/zend-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName zend.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

`/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       zend.local
127.0.0.1       localhost`

Comment: Look in the server logs to see what caused the error.

Comment: I had similar issue. To solve this, I'd suggest to cancel all edits in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/zend-default.conf` and instead create a new `.htaccess` in the root folder of your server with following content: `RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1 [L] `

Comment: Thank you! But problem was in rewrite-module.
I forgot enable Apache's rewrite-module,

sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score -1):

if I remember correctly you have to enable mod_rewrite in your apache2.